# Remove the static int from this MatchEvaluator

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a proprietary string mask to the .net equivalent of it.
For that I need to exchange every occurance of [someText] with {aDigit}.

```
private static int hits = 0;
private static object hitsLock = new object();

public static string ConvertSdsFileMaskToStringMask(string sdsFileMaskString) {
    Regex bracketsExpression = new Regex(@"\[[^[]*]");
    lock (hitsLock)
    {
        hits = 0;
        return bracketsExpression.Replace(sdsFileMaskString, ReplaceSquareWithAngularBrackets);
    }
}
private static string ReplaceSquareWithAngularBrackets(Match m) {
    string result = String.Format("{{{0}}}", hits.ToString());
    hits++;
    return result;
}
```

It works. But both expressions need to know each other's workings and are depending on the hits counter. I feel this could be improved. Ideally both have no dependency on each other. Any suggestions? 
This can probably be done better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use an anonymous method or lambda expression:

```
public static string ConvertSdsFileMaskToStringMask(string sdsFileMaskString) 
{
    Regex bracketsExpression = new Regex(@"\[[^[]*]");
    int hits = 0;
    return bracketsExpression.Replace(sdsFileMaskString, match => 
    {
        string result = String.Format("{{{0}}}", hits.ToString());
        hits++;
        return result;    
    });
}
```

This will capture the *local* variable in a new (compiler-generated) type, getting rid of the "globalness".

*If* you're happy with side-effects, you could make the lambda expression simpler, too. I'd also get rid of the call to String.Format in this case, as all those braces are confusing:

```
public static string ConvertSdsFileMaskToStringMask(string sdsFileMaskString) 
{
    Regex bracketsExpression = new Regex(@"\[[^[]*]");
    int hits = 0;
    return bracketsExpression.Replace(sdsFileMaskString, 
        match => "{" + (hits++) + "}");
}
```

Comment: Aha! The verry first time where the whole ++hits vs hits++ thing comes into play :)
Didn't think of lambda's yet. Great!

Answer (score 1):

By using a lambda, and a local variable hits, C# will create a closure :

```
public static string ConvertSdsFileMaskToStringMask(string sdsFileMaskString)
{
   Regex bracketsExpression = new Regex(@"\[[^[]*]");
   int hits = 0;
   return bracketsExpression.Replace(sdsFileMaskString, 
       m => string.Format("{{{0}}}", hits++));
}
```

will be sufficient

The hits variable is encapsulated in the lambda closure and will be reused inside all lambda calls, but will be distinct for several ConvertSdsFileMaskToStringMask calls.

Comment: Pretty much equivalent to Skeet's. Can only give one post the answer though.

Comment: I believe you need to assign hits a value. Not that I've checked, I have to admit.

Comment: Noticed you didn't assign a value to hits before using though. And there's one bracket missing to close the Replace call. But the intention is perfectly clear.

Comment: Damn, even beat me to the comment :p